# The shabbat-yom-tov tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

We have the following tags:

- [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat), 248 questions
- [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov), 48 questions
- [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov), 7 questions

One question tagged with the [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov) also has either of the others: and it has both. Sixteen other questions are also tagged with both [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov).

What are all these tags for?

- Is there a semantic difference between a question's having both [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) and its having [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov)?
- Should [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov) exist at all?
- Should every question now tagged with both [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) be instead tagged [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov)?

---

**UPDATE:** I've effected the following, from the answers and comments below: the [shabbas-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbas-yomtov) tag is now merged into the [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) tag, whose wiki indicates that it should be used also for questions that apply to *shabas* and *yom tov* equally. I have added the same advice to the [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) tag wiki also.

Comment: It seems below that we reached somewhat of a conclusion on the matter. Was it ever implemented?

Comment: @DoubleAA, see update to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we should replace the shabbat and yomtov tags with a combined tag; it impedes tag search, as now you can't use the yomtov link to find all the yomtov questions.

Let's tag entries with whatever subset of shabbat, yomtov, and melacha is appropriate to each question.  (Or if there are other considerations besides melacha, apply those tags instead.)  If a question is about, say, differences between Shabbat and Yom Tov, it gets both.  If it's about Shabbat restrictions that also apply on Yom Tov, it gets shabbat (only) -- we already understand that shabbat can apply to yom-tov, so we wouldn't double-tag.

Comment: +1. So you're saying the [tag:shabbat-yomtov] tag shouldn't exist at all. Do you think questions that apply equally to _Shabas_ and _yom tov_ should be tagged with both [tag:shabbat] and [tag:yom-tov]?

Comment: @msh210, I don't. That would include a large subset of Shabbat questions and would therefore introduce unnecessary cumber.

Comment: @msh210, yes, that's what I'm saying: no shabbat-yomtov tag, and apply the shabbat and yomtov tags to questions they apply to, even if there's overlap.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, oh, I see what you're saying now, so let me reconsider my previous comment.  if there's nothing "yom-tov"y about a question other than that it involves melacha forbidden on both, I wouldn't tag it yomtov.  But if it's a question about differences between shabbat and yomtov I would.

Comment: Ah, then I guess you and the second paragraph in [Isaac Moses's answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/439) agree.

Comment: @msh210, well, if there are really only 7 of them right now we should take a quick skim to make sure they really all belong in shabbat.  So I wasn't sure about merge but that probably makes sense; mostly I want to kill the shabbat-yomtov tag.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, what [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov) is supposed to be is more like [melacha-creative-work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melacha-creative-work).

Or, perhaps we should just merge it into [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and put a note in [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat)'s wiki indicating that this tag will be used for any issues that apply equally to Shabbat and Yom Tov, while any issues that apply differently on these two types of days will have both [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov).

Comment: +1. Note that "issues that apply equally to Shabbat and Yom Tov" may well be just those covered by [tag:melacha-creative-work], which brings us back to your first paragraph.

Comment: @msh210, well, there are shared "Zachor"-oriented issues as well, potentially. Also Rabbinic "Shamor"-oriented issues, which may or may not deserve classification under "melacha."